# Data not being added to Firebase collection ( cloud firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function in React native to add a chat as a collection item to Firestore database.

The function seems to be working but nothing is being added when I look at the cloud firestore.

Here is my firebase config file:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
(fake data)
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "myApi key",
    authDomain: "domain.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "domain",
    storageBucket: "domain.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1234556",
    appId: "1:532323:web:4ae123asdasad"
};

let app;

if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();

const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db,auth};
```

My React Component:

```
import {Button, Input} from 'react-native-elements'
import React, {useLayoutEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { db } from '../firebase'

export const AddChatScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "Add a new chat",
      headerBackTitle: "Chats",
    })
  }, [navigation]);
  
  const createChat = async () => {
    console.log(input)
    await db.collection('chats').add({
      chatName:input,
    }).then(() => {
      navigation.goBack()
    }).catch(error => alert(error))
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input
      placeholder='Enter a chat name' 
      value={input} 
      onChangeText={(text) =>setInput(text)}
      onSubmitEditing={createChat}
      leftIcon={
        <AntDesign name="wechat" size={24} color="black" />
      }
      />
      <Button onPress={createChat} title="Create new Chat"/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

As you can tell I am logging the user input and that logs ok but upon button click to create a new chat, that logs but no register of the collection.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into your console have you updated your roles?

Comment: what do you mean by updating my roles?

Comment: Sorry I mean to say is that have you added rules to write the db in your console?

Comment: ah no worries, have not added any rules, do I need to?

Comment: Yes! you have to add them before using it

Comment: there is one "default" rule there I believe:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 9, 3);
    }
  }
}
Is this not enough?

Comment: @RandomDeveloper you can control write and read access based on user roles https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: Those rules grant full read and write access until September 3rd, so are not causing any problems at the moment. --- "The function seems to be working" Can you clarify what you mean by that? Does it execute the `then` block of the write operation, and this navigate back? Or are you getting the alert of the `catch` block?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen nothing happens basically. I click the button, I can tell the function is working cause it logs the `input` variable but it's not navigating back as it's supposed to and there isn't anything in the collection or any error logs

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as I wrote this, it seemed to have worked. No difference at all so not sure what happen there

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @RandomDeveloper  We'll chalk it up to some ephemeral problem then. :)